# How to serve image with http module as a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, http

I've built a server which handles some type of requests (html and image files).
When I'm requesting the files with the browser, I'm able to view the html file or the requested image.

I've tried also to build a client script which requesting files. When I'm requesting the html file, I receive it properly.
But when I'm requesting the image file, it is being received but I can't view the image.

How can I receive the image as a file?

Relevant path of the server:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(`${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
    console.log(`From: ${req.connection.remoteAddress}`);
    let fileName = req.url;
    if (utils.isFileExistsInDirectory(__dirname, fileName)) {
        if (_.includes(fileName, '.html')) {
            fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/${fileName}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
                    res.end('A trouble occurred with the file.');
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end(data);
                }
            });
        } else if (fileName.match(/.png$/)) {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'images', fileName), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
                    res.end('A trouble occurred with the file.');
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
                    res.end(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/${fileName}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
                    res.end('A trouble occurred with the file.');
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    res.end(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
        res.end('File not found.');
    }
});
```

Relevant part of the client:

```
const req = http.request(options, res => {
    let responseBody = '';
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        responseBody += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(`${__dirname}/${dir}`)){
            fs.mkdirSync(`${__dirname}/${dir}`);
        }
        fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/${dir}/${path}`, responseBody, err => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });
});
req.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${err}`);
});
req.end();
```

Comment: The `fileName.match(/.png$/)` is wrong as `String.prototype.match()` returns an array or `null`. You probably mean `/\.png$/.test(filename)` to get a boolean response. Also I note you're only looking at the file extension. There are better ways to do content detection for the MIME type which you really should be doing instead.

Comment: Just FYI. Even the [`String.protype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) manual page on MDN says the exact same things that you usually mean [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the comments! I'll improve my content detection

Comment: Well it's not just "improve". I'm telling you where your bug is. What you think is a test on the filename does not return a boolean value. So fix it and the code will at least brach correctly for a `.png` image. Right now it's returning a MIME type of `'text/plain'` on the default logic branch. That's why you don't see the image.

Comment: @NeilLunn no, I'm sorry but you're wrong. I wouldn't see the image within the browser if it was returned the `text/plain`. Moreover, I logged before the `res.end()` and clearly it goes to `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});`. Maybe the condition is not excellent, but it's working. I'll improve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try to encode image in base64 string

```
    my.get("/getimg", function(req, res)
    {
        var img = new Buffer(data, 'base64');

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': img.length
        });
        res.end(img); 
    });
```

Comment: Well copied from another answer. So well copied that you failed to understand the part of what you copied from that actually answered the question asked here. And FYI that was not the Base64 part, though there was something correct.

Comment: It still makes the same problem.